# Wordpress users should auto login to zend application

Tags: wordpress, zend-framework

I have a wordpress website([www.mywpsite.com](http://www.mywpsite.com)) and zend application([www.myzendapp.com](http://www.myzendapp.com)) hosted in different servers. Need to have a menu link in wordpress site which should redirect to zend application with user login(logged in wordpress users should not login again in zend app). Can anybody help to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This is called **Single Sign-On**. The idea is:

- Set up an authorization API in WordPress.
- Set up a separate auth component in Zend.
- Ping the WordPress endpoint when a user hits a
  protected page in the Zend App and then manually log in the user.
  (This would create a second set of auth cookies)

Comment: Thanks, will try the solution